# HTML5 Websocket Live-Application Limitations

Tags: html, websocket

I'm developing a HTML5 Websocket-Based application which should notify the users in real-time about different events. The client connect to the server, send a handshake with some securitytoken, the server check if the securitytoken is valid and add the client to the list of active clients. Now he get notifications on special events.

Because there are different notifications from multiplice applications, there is a notification-core where handle the basics of the connection and also the authentification because this is always the same. The core can be accessed from applications, with them they can communicate to the server.

Does it make sense or is it necessary to insert some limitations in the core? For example tracking the user-ip and refuse the connection if the user has more than lets say 3 connections to the server in the last 10 seconds to prevent flood-attacks.

In my oppinion I think it can reduce serverload if someone try to crash my service by holding the F5 key or using some botnet as long as he isn't sending so much traffic to my server that my connection can't handle that much.

I'm using socket.io if this is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to protect your application from malicious attacks, there are many, many things you would need to consider and it is important to prioritize those things and spend your development time on the things that could most impact your service.  I would think that creating multiple webSocket connections would be very low on the priority list way behind operations in your service that actually change state such as cause writes to a database, etc...  Modern servers can easily hold tens of thousands of sockets and it costs little server load to just be sending the same notification to lots of sockets.

In addition, using the IP address as something to limit by can cause problems because larger organizations may use NAT to share a single IP address among many users for outbound connections.  If you are going to limit by user, it's much better to limit by a userID (something each user uniquely logs in with).